# Imputation of missing data

Tags: forecasting, prediction, data-imputation, census

My goal is to estimate nutrition indicators of children less than 5 years old at the subnational level (say provinces) in a given country.  I have two datasets:

i) survey data that includes this nutritional information and some variables regarding the socioeconomic status of the household in which the children lives.
ii) census data, which includes *only* the socioeconomic characteristics information, as in the survey data (no nutrition).

The methodology (called nutrition mapping) relies on two stages: first, using survey data, model the nutrition status (left-hand variable) using the household characteristics (right-hand variables) and get a vector of '$\hat{b}$'.  Second, using $\hat{b}$, impute the nutrition values using the more comprehensive information from census data.  What I would like to have is some measure of the *quality* of the prediction/forecast in this second stage. How can I get some kind of robust confidence level or standard error that includes the first stage modelling?  Any orientation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could always just make cross-validated or bootstrapped predictions, treating your imputation strategy as a predictive model like any other.

Comment: Also what kind of model are you using? With a Bayesian method you could use WAIC or something like that

Comment: @ssdecontrol: In the first stage I use OLS.  Sadly, I barely know the Bayesian method of estimation.

Comment: Isn't this just a prediction exercise? Or are you then using $\hat b$ as an input to some other model? If so, what is that other model? Also, how many $b$ variables are there?

Comment: Number of b variables is 25.  This would be just an exercise of prediction, the b's are used with another set of information (census)

Comment: Then is it fair to say that this problem reduces to "quantifying the predictive performance of a model for $b$"?

Comment: Hi @ssdecontrol, I think that is correct